# How can I connect to the ftp server? ftp command returns 550

Tags: ftp

`$ ftp example.com 51225`

```
Connected to example.com.
220 ProFTPD Server ready.

$ Name (example.com:ra): me@mydomain.com

550 SSL/TLS required on the control channel
ftp: Login failed.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
```

Neither `man ftp` nor `ftp --help` give me the slightest clue

Answer (score 3):

Your FTP server requires TLS encryption. Your client can't provide it.

Sometimes this encrypted version of FTP is called FTP/S. (Don't confuse it with a completely unrelated protocol SFTP.)

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue using [lftp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lftp) instead of ftp